# Java web application running on Tomcat unable to execute SQL queries with DB Connection pooling

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, tomcat6, connection-pooling

I've come across similar questions many times here on Stack Overflow, however, I haven't been able to get it right.

I'm trying to use Database connection pooling in Tomcat 6 + MySQL ( on AWS RDS )
These are the parameters I have configured.

( I'm closing the connection from my Java code also )

```
<Resource name="jdbc/awsDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
                initialSize="10"
                testWhileIdle="true"
                maxActive="30"
                maxAge="3600"
            maxIdle="5"
                maxWait="3000"
                removeAbandoned="true"
                logAbandoned="false"
                validationQuery="SELECT 1"
                removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="15000"
                username="sbose78" password="XXXXX"
                driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  
                url="jdbc:mysql://xxxxrds.amazonaws.com:3306/health?autoReconnect=true" />
```

The application works great for the first few database queries and after that the database connection hangs indefinitely.

From the connection logs I've noticed that the connection pooling works good , however, Even when there are 10+ connections in SLEEP state, a new database query takes indefinite time to execute.

I end up re-starting the server in most cases.

What configuration mistake am I doing?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your query is using all the indexed columns in the where clause.If you are sure about the connection pool, then most probaably the problem will be with query itself.